# Troubleshooting 404 errors when reverting from Classic mode to integrated pipeline on IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7

Ideas to troubleshoot 404 errors when reverting from Classic mode to integrated pipeline on IIS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having previously set a Wildcard Script Map under classic mode, you may be missing the UrlRouting Handler.

Ensure wildcard script map is removed from Handler Mappings.

Then add the UrlRouting handler if not present:

```
Your Website >> Handler Mappings >> Add Managed Handler

Request Path: UrlRouting.axd
Type: System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Name: UrlRouting Handler
```